# MSM open_basedir path

Tags: multi-site-manager

I have a MSM installation.
The hosting provider (shared hosting) don't want to desactivate open_basedir (security risks) so I have to enter a custom open_basedir path to circumvent restrictions.

But I don't know what to put as open_basedir path.

The hierarchy of my MSM websites :

└── domain1
    ├── admin.php
    ├── index.php
    ├── images
    ├── system
    └── themes

└── domain2
    ├── admin.php
    └── index.php

My server path is like this (don't worry, not the real one) :
/home/www/hosting/domain1.com/web/domain1site/

and for the other site :
/home/www/hosting/domain1.com/web/domain2site/

Does anyone know ? Thanks in advance.